# Understanding the simplest LLVM IR

Tags: syntax, llvm

I transform the simplest C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

to its LLVM IR, using

```
clang -emit-llvm -S hello.c
```

The generated IR is:

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1
  ret i32 0
}
```

However, I do not understand this IR. (LLVM doc helps but not that much for beginners)

1. Why do we have `%1 = alloca i32, align 4` ? What does it correspond to in the original code?
2. Same question for `store i32 0, i32* %1`
3. Does alloca mean allocation on the stack (instead of the dynamic allocation)?
4. What do 'align 4' mean?

Comment: The align indicates that the memory operation should be aligned to 4 bytes. I am not sure about the rest.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
 define i32 @main() #0
```

This defines a function called `main` that returns a 32 bit integer. The `#0` means to use the attributes named `#0` for the function. For example, there may be something like `attributes #0 = { alwaysinline alignstack=4 }` in the IR, and these attributes will be applied to `main`.

```
%1 = alloca i32, align 4
```

This allocates a 32 bit integer on the stack. `%1` is the name of  a pointer to this location on the stack. The `align 4` ensures that the address will be a multiple of 4

```
store i32 0, i32* %1
```

This sets the 32 bit integer pointed to by `%1` to the 32 bit value 0. It's like saying `*x = 1` in C++

```
ret i32 0
```

This returns from the function with a 32 bit return value of 0

The assignment is odd, considering that you don't have a local variable in `main`. LLVM uses `BasicBlock` to represent groups of instructions, and a basic block has an exit point and a list of instructions. My guess would be that the compiler has decided to use the `return` as the exit from the basic block and has opted to put in at least one instruction into the block. The assignment is basically a no-op.

Answer (score 20):

The `%n` are virtual registers that will be resolved to actual registers when generating code for the target machine.

The `i32` is there for type information. In the original code it was an `int` which your compiler took to be 32-bit integer.

`alloca` is for allocating space on the stack. In this example it is `i32` (32-bit integer) so you can load in the 0 for the return value. `align 4` gives this allocation 4 byte alignment i.e. the stack pointer will be on a 4 byte aligned address.

It isn't the most efficient representation but that is not the aim if IR. IR should be portable to different architectures. It is then down to the backend to produce efficient machine code.

[LLVM Language Reference Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html)

Why `alloca` and `store` are there is to do with this being the `main` function. If you had called this function something else, the IR would just contain `ret` as you expected. From examining the assembly produced for main it appears to be related to the stack base pointer
but I don't fully understand why it is there. Time to pull out the C standard I think.

Update: I couln't find anything in the C standard but it seems clang does this for every main function. I don't know the clang code base well enough to track it down though.

Update: See comments with Bill Lynch below. These instuctions are there:

> for the possible implicit `return 0` that main functions have

Comment: Thank you. Then why do we need %1 here(my questions #1 and #2)?

Comment: @zell: It's not necessary. If you enabled the optimizers (with -O3 for example) it would be removed.

Comment: @Bill. Thank you. Still even for an inefficient IR, there should be a reason %1 is used. What is the rational that LLVM IR needs an extra %1 (I totally understand that optimization will rule away it).?

Comment: @zell: The `%1` is there for the possible implicit `return 0;` that main functions have. It's basically an artifact of how they do code generation.

Comment: @BillLynch do you have a source for this fact? It seems strange to me since what help does pushing 0 have on a return value?

Comment: @DrYap: http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/CodeGen/CGCall.cpp?revision=224047&view=markup#l1638

Answer (score 3):

Variables are usually put on the stack in unoptimized builds for debugging reasons. In optimized builds that use real registers the value might disappear before the function exits.

The comment about portability isn't precisely correct, if this IR was passed through 'opt' it would eliminate the stack store.

Comment: But there isn't a variable in main to try and store on the stack. Having looked at lots of other clang output it always seems to store this 0 on the stack in main.

Comment: The value being placed there is the return value.

Comment: Thank you Colin. Awesome information.  Adding `-O3` to the ll generation in my own caes made the IR sooo much easier to understand :-)